# Incorrect hyperlink (with hyperref) to tcolorbox theorems with section counters

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox

In the following MWE, a click on the hyperlink created with `\ref{thm:labelOfTheorem}` does not work as expected: Instead of jumping to the theorem, the PDF jumps to the definition.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[number within = section]{theobox}{Theorem}{}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=theobox]{defbox}{Definition}{}{def}
%\newtcbtheorem{defbox}{Definition}{}{def} % A) Use this line instead of the above and the reference works

\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

\begin{defbox}{}{labelOfDefinition}
    Something defined here
\end{defbox}

\vfill
\section{Another Section} % B) Comment this line out and the reference works

\begin{theobox}{}{labelOfTheorem}
    A Theorem
\end{theobox}

The proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:labelOfTheorem} is left as an exercise to the reader.


\end{document}
```

The wanted behavior of the hyperlink can be achieved with two ways (see comments in MWE):

- A) Do not `use counter from=theobox` for `defbox`
- B) Do not start a new `section`

Of course neither A) nor B) are solutions.

It is clear, that the linking breaks due to the section counter. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are resetting the counter with the section the `\the<counter>` representation is no longer unique and so hyperref creates two destination with the same name. You get a warning in the log:

```
destination with the same identifier (name{tcb@cnt@theobox.1}) has been 
already used, duplicate ignored
```

The typical method to avoid this is to define a \theH-version of the counter representation:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[number within = section]{theobox}{Theorem}{}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=theobox]{defbox}{Definition}{}{def}
%\newtcbtheorem{defbox}{Definition}{}{def} % A) Use this line instead of the above and the reference works

\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\theHtcb@cnt@theobox{\thesection.\arabic{tcb@cnt@theobox}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}

\begin{defbox}{}{labelOfDefinition}
    Something defined here
\end{defbox}

\vfill
\section{Another Section} % B) Comment this line out and the reference works

\begin{theobox}{}{labelOfTheorem}
    A Theorem
\end{theobox}

The proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:labelOfTheorem} is left as an exercise to the reader.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! For anyone else who like me has never heard of \theH counters before, more information is found in the [documentation of hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).